# I want to perform a simple tensorial contraction

Tags: tensors

I want to perform a simple tensorial contraction like, if KroneckerDelta[i, j] is contracted with some arbitrary tensor A_{lkj} (not-necessarily symmetric) it should give the answer as A_{lki}. Is their any way to do it?

Comment: We need more details. Would you like to do that for numerical or for symbolical tensors?

Comment: Hi. Analytically, I want to do evaluate some integration like A_{jmi} \int g_j g_k exp{-(g_x^2+g_y^2+g_z^2}d g_x d g_y d g_z. The final result will be \pi^(3/2)*A_{kmi}/2 where A_{jmi} is the "j-m-i"th component of an arbitrary third rank tensor A.

Answer (score 2):

The following code

```
tc[KroneckerDelta[i_, j_], A_[l_, k_, j_]] := A[l, k, i];
```

seems to do what you want. The expression

```
tc[KroneckerDelta[i, j], A[l, k, j]] == A[l, k, i]
```

evaluates to `True` as it seems you wanted. If this is not doing what you want, please give an actual example of the result you expect.